# Change mysql column rows

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a mysql table structure :

```
emails( id , name , email )
```

how i can change the order of the table to

```
emails( id , email ,name  )
```

Comment: can you explain why you would like to do that?

Comment: There should be no good reason to do this.

Comment: i have two database and i want to migrate data from one to another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [this](http://nabtron.com/alter-sequence-columns-field-database-table-mysql-phpmyadmin/1914/) is what you want.

```
ALTER TABLE emails MODIFY COLUMN name `name_data_type` after email;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ALTER table `emails`
       MODIFY COLUMN `name` your_data_type
       AFTER `email`
```

Read more in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE emails MODIFY COLUMN name AFTER email
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new table with a different name
2. Copy the values of the old table to the new table
3. Delete the old table
4. Create a table with the old name
5. Copy the values again

However, this should not be necessary if you adhere to best practices (like stating the names of the columns that you want to retrieve and the names of the columns that you want to set).

Comment: 1-3 agree (and that's what Mysql does behind the screens anyways if we can believe the doco), replace 4 and 5 by `alter table ... rename to ...`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment you added, ie you want to copy table data between databases, have a look at [SquirrelSQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) and its DBCopy plugin, that might provide you with a more universal approach and leaner, faster way to achieve your goal.  And it works between databases of different brands as well.